# Guidance on assigning full phone numbers to voip servers for incoming calls

Tags: linux, voip

I set up my own asterisk voip server and i was able to make calls to my extension but how do i get it so I would have an actual phone number people from the outside can call in. lets say i want the phone number

555-1234 and if someone calls that number it gets routed to my voip server then i process it and etc..
I was presuming that this would work similarly like DNS where you go buy a number and then point it to your server with an A record. Then from there nginx processes the server request and provides appropriate web pages and so on.

Some information on this would be fantastic as I have no idea where to go for this kind of stuff and google hits isnt revealing a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get a DID (Direct Inward Dialing) from a VoIP provider. There are many ITSP providers up there that can provide DID and then send it to your Asterisk server (called SIP Trunking) and from there you can configure Asterisk to terminate the call on specific extension or IVR.

Also, DIDs are usually provided by tier 1 carrier (companies like Bell Canada, AT&T, Verizon etc). Again, DID (Direct Inward Dialing) is not something you can simply advertise from your Asterisk server unless of course you want to allow people to call you by IP. For example, 5551234@YourAsteriskIP will make sure extension ring. But users from a non sip devices (ie landline) cannot call your number.